# Babel Not compiling. Unexpected Token

Tags: django, reactjs, babeljs

This has been asked before but I have clearly set up the steps for this. What am I doing wrong or setting up wrong?

I get the following error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Login.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (52:10)

50 |     };
51 | 
> 52 |     const element = <div>
```

The following is my .babelrc:

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2", "env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

and then finally my webpack.config.js

```
module: {
   rules: [
    {
        //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders     on all
        //.js and .jsx files
        test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2','@babel/preset-env']
        }
    },
```

I have installed the babel presets and all the packages required.

I am just trying to use the JSX coding style. I am still new to this environment.

Comment: this isn't about babel, it's just that you have a syntax error somewhere in your `Login.js` file (probably a missing `}`)

Comment: please post you login page here